# Output a byte stream to stdout

Tags: java, base64, stdout, encryption

I have following function, which decrypts a base64 file and writes it to a txt file. However, instead of it writing to a text file, I want it to output to stdout. Can you please suggest how we could do that

```
CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(os, cipher);
    doCopy(is, cos);

}

public static void doCopy(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[64];
    int numBytes;
    while ((numBytes = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        os.write(bytes, 0, numBytes);
    }
```

So instead of os.write writing the stream to a txt file, it should write it to stdout.

Comment: This would generally be `System.out.write`

Comment: I tried doing that below, but it would not yield me the correct value still

while ((numBytes = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
   //os.write(bytes, 0, numBytes);
   System.out.write(bytes);
  
   
  }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) (class of stdout) has a write method which could be called to write a byte[] to stdout.